# Duplicate documents in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am sending one document to Elastic  5.5 from Logstash. But I am getting duplicate documents in Elasticsearch, two documents with different IDs but same fields. Below I am showing only index , type and id.

```
"hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "logstash-2017.09.01",
        "_type": "threat",
        "_id": "AV4-7XhNlO-DC0yfkKOf",
        "_score": 1
      },
      {
        "_index": "logstash-2017.09.01",
        "_type": "threat",
        "_id": "AV4-7XhklO-DC0yfkKOg",
        "_score": 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Yes, ofcourse 2 different id depict 2 different documents in elastic. They must not be same. You could be missing something minute.

Comment: I compared all fields, the only difference is id;)

Comment: $ diff es1 es2
16c16
<         "_id" : "AV4-7XhklO-DC0yfkKOg",
---
>         "_id" : "AV4-7XhNlO-DC0yfkKOf",

Comment: If you could share your logstash config that's generating these docs.

Comment: You need to use your own IDs, the content of the source will not be inspected by ES at all. Pretty sure you don't have any `document_id` setting  in the `elasticsearch` output of your logstash config.

Comment: yeah, I followed www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-lessons-handling-duplicates and added uuid, now I dont have duplicates